# Xcode 4.1 Instruments Hardly Working For Me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instruments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug with starting Instruments via Profile under XCode 4.1 Build 4B110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801310/bug-with-starting-instruments-via-profile-under-xcode-4-1-build-4b110)

Instruments used to work fine, however now that I have the new 4.1 Xcode on Lion, it is extremely slow and I have to wait about 5 min before it is responsive.  Is anyone else having this same problem?  I am using iOS simulator too.

I have already tried reinstalling and uninstalling Xcode a few times as well.

Comment: Here same question with a workaround in the comments: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801310/problem-with-starting-instruments-via-profile-under-xcode-4-1-build-4b110][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801310/problem-with-starting-instruments-via-profile-under-xcode-4-1-build-4b110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/authorization, add following:

```
<key>com.apple.instruments.process.analysis</key>
<dict>
<key>authenticate-user</key>
<false/>
<key>class</key>
<string>user</string>
<key>comment</key>
<string>Rights for Instruments</string>
<key>group</key>
<string>admin</string>
<key>shared</key>
<true/>
<key>timeout</key>
<integer>36000</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: Couldn't find this /etc/authorization any where?  I have Lion.

Comment: Worked for me on SnowLeopard.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching Instruments separately, instead of using the Profile build option in XCode.  You should be able to run your app in Simulator, then open Instruments, select Leaks, and then choose your app as the Target in Instruments (Choose Target, Attach to Process, in the System section).

Hopefully, this is something that will be fixed by Apple, but you should be able to at least check for leaks like this.

[UPDATE]
I'm getting some weird leaks doing this, so, I'm not sure if it's completely working or just me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach of running my iApp, then selecting Instruments.  When I tried to then start up Instruments, the iOS Simulator quit.