# iOS Simulator and Instruments freeze

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to do an iOS app and when I press CMD+I to launch Instruments to check for memory leaks the simulator freezes after a couple of gestures and so does Instruments.
Sometimes after a minute (or more) it works, but it's driving me nuts :(

I have Mac OS Lion and Xcode 4 (Lion version downloaded from Apple's dev portal).

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the fix from here:
[Bug with starting Instruments via Profile under XCode 4.1 Build 4B110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801310/problem-with-starting-instruments-via-profile-under-xcode-4-1-build-4b110)

Basically, after Instruments starts your app, Command-Tab to Xcode and back. I had the same problem but this fixed it.

Comment: Command-Tab to anywhere and back a few times. Doest have to be xcode. This one almost made be bash the screen with my head .. o_O

Comment: sure enough ... Thanks Rob, my screen owes you one (fist stopped just short of the Apple logo on startup).